# How to assign a return value from a SQL Server Function to a Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have function that returns a Date value. I need to assign that return value to a declared variable.

```
Declare @Duedate Date
Set @Duedate = SELECT dbo.TATDueDateCaluator('2019-05-10',2)
Select @Duedate
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is scalar valued you don't even need a `SELECT`. Just

```
SET @duedate = dbo.tatduedatecaluator('2019-05-10', 2);
```

should do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign directly in a `SELECT`:

```
Declare @Duedate Date;

SELECT @DueDate = dbo.TATDueDateCaluator('2019-05-10', 2);

Select @Duedate;
```

Your code doesn't work because subqueries always need their own parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have doubt is this Set the value to the variable or not? Because we usually to assign a value by using SET Variable_name = Value. Right?

Comment: @SanjithM . . . Yes, this sets the variable.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define it in one line:

```
Declare @Duedate Date = dbo.TATDueDateCaluator('2019-05-10',2)

Select Duedate
```